# AngularJS ajax resulting in two calls for html & json

Tags: angularjs, nancy

So I turned on network capture in my web browser to have a look at my ajax calls coming out of AngularJS. For every call made, there seems to be two results:

```
URL|Protocol|Method|Result|Type|Received|Taken
/p/jobs/03512dc8-6f25-49ea-bdff-0028ac2023cb|HTTP|GET|301|text/html|408 B|< 1 ms
/p/jobs/03512dc8-6f25-49ea-bdff-0028ac2023cb|HTTP|GET|200|application/json|0.79 KB|15 ms
```

It looks like it's attempting to request HTML first, getting a 301 and then requesting the JSON. How can I eliminate the request for HTML? I'm using $resource to do this but I'd also like to see an example for $http.

Also, the receiving framework is NancyFX for .NET. Perhaps there's a header I need to specify to make sure it always returns JSON? I've tried the "Accept" header but it seems to make no difference. It's as if Nancy is always trying to return a View first before switching to JSON.

Javascript code (translated slightly from TypeScript):

```
$resource(jobUrl, {}, { get: {method: "GET", isArray: false }});
```

Nancy code:

```
    public class JobService : NancyModule
{
    public static readonly string Prefix = "/p/jobs";

    WebLogger logger;

    public JobService(WebLogger logger)
        : base(Prefix)
    {
        this.logger = logger;

        Get[""] = _ => GetJobs();
        Get["/{id}"] = _ => GetJob(_.id);
        Get["/{id}/nodes"] = _ => GetNodes(_.id);
        Get["/{id}/faults"] = _ => GetFaults(_.id);
    }

    Job GetJob(string id)
    {
        lock (logger)
        {
            if (logger.JobGuid != id)
            {
                Context.Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                return null;
            }

            return MakeJob();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the Nancy module handling these requests and the Javascript causing the requests?

Comment: Okay, I've posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

Some part of your code will be helpful, but lets try - you have put character `/` at the end of **$resource** definition. Angular has asked server for content for directory, server response with **header 301** - redirect to file as Angular expects some data response than directory listing.

Comment: Nope, no trailing forward slashes in my URLs.